# oracle exadata processing after reading from disk

Tags: oracle, exadata

I'm trying to figure out where the data gets processed in an Oracle Exadata system after the data is pulled off of the disk.

From my understanding, when you run a query, the data(rows) has to get fetched from disk, but where is it putting this data to process after its off of the disk? Is it going to RAM (SGA or PGA), flash cache, swap space on another disk, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rows are transfered from exadata cell node to SGA/PGA on compute nodes with an internal data transmission protocol known as iDB.